# Use Windows User Control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to create a windows user control and use it in asp.net.
i create the windows user control and it work correctly in a test windows project.
But when i add it to my webform the control doesn't show and it display "a control type was not specified".

here is my user control:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

Public Class UserControl1

```
Public Property Title() As String
    Get
        Return Me.GroupBox1.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.GroupBox1.Text = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub
```

End Class

and My webform:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <object id="MyWinControl1" height="200" width="200" classid="~/HostWinControlInAspx.dll#HostWinControlInAspx.UserControl1" viewastext>
            <param name="Title" value="My Title" />
        </object>

   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I've never heard of a Windows User Control being uses in a webform. I have always created Web User Controls for use in my web project (ascx files) I then reference them in the webform and use them in the mark-up where I need.

Comment: i want to use light pen in my webforms to append signature or other comments.
inkedit and inkpicture can be used just in windows forms.
i m searching for a solution.
do you know any component to do this?